# For what simple closed curves does the equation hold?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^{2}+z+1} = 0.$$

I know that by Cauchy's Theorem, if $f$ is analytic everywhere on and inside a simple closed curve, then $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 0$. So I thought that the above equation would hold for any simple closed curve not containing the roots of the denominator.

However, the solution in the book says it is true for any closed curve containing neither OR both of the roots.

I don't get the “or both” part.

Edit: Part of my confusion lies in the fact that in my class, we did an example:

$$\int_{|z|=9} \frac{-3z+2}{(z-6)(z-2)}\,dz$$
where both roots lied in the region, and yet the answer was non-zero. So it seems that the “or both” part is not always true, but for the problem I am working on it is true. Can someone explain the difference?

Edit#2: In the case that one of the roots lies outside the curve, say, the root $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3i}{2}$, this means that the integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3i}{2}}$ is analytic everywhere in that curve, and so it has value $0$. Then the other integral has value some constant multiplied by $2\pi i$, and so the sum of the two integrals is non-zero.

Is edit#2 correct?

Comment: The essential difference of the two examples is the fact, that the latter integrand has a pole at infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ and $s$ are the roots of $x^2+x+1$, then$$\frac1{x^2+x+1}=\frac1{(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac{\frac1{s-r}}{x-s}-\frac{\frac1{s-r}}{x-r}.$$Therefore (in the “both” case),$$\int_\gamma\frac1{x^2+x+1}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\left(\frac1{s-r}-\frac1{s-r}\right)=0.$$

Comment: On the first string of three equalities, how did you get the numerators $\frac{1}{s-r}$ (on the last equality)? Is this just a formula for partial fraction decomposition? (also, would you mind taking a look at the edit on my post?)

Comment: Here, what I did was to compute the decomposition of $\frac1{(x-r)(x-s)}$ in partial fractions, yes. In the example that you mentioned in your edition, what you get is$$\frac{-3z+2}{(z-6)(z-2)}=\frac {-4}{z-6}+\frac1{z-2},$$Now, the coefficients are $-4$ and $1$; therefore, they do not cancel each other.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. Can you check to see if my edit#2 is a correct reasoning as to why the integral is non-zero if one of the roots is outside of the curve?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Or you can apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Thanks. We haven't covered the residue theorem in my course yet, so I was trying to stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{1}{(z-z_-)(z-z_+)}\\
\Rightarrow 
\text{Res}(f(z),z_-)+\text{Res}(f(z),z_+)=\frac1{z_--z_+}+\frac1{z_+-z_-}=0.
$$

Notice that if a meromorphic function has no poles at infinity the same (zero) result will hold for any contour encompassing all poles of the function.